# Iterating through map

Tags: java, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through a map and remove certain elements to construct a controlled vocabulary. Here is my code:

```
    public static Map<String, Integer> controlVocab(Map<String, Integer> docf){
    Set<String> set = docf.keySet();
    Iterator<String> itr = set.iterator();
    for (Map.Entry <String, Integer> entry : docf.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getValue()<50){
            docf.remove(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return docf;
}
```

But I keep getting this error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1429)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1463)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1461)
    at org.tartarus.snowball.TestApp.controlVocab(TestApp.java:114)
    at org.tartarus.snowball.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:619)

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this makes sense: as the [official oracle documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it.

Maybe a best way is to collect the element that you want delete in a new List and then iterating on this list remove the correspondent entry in the original Map.

Try something like that:

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map.Entry <String, Integer> entry : docf.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue()<50){
            mylist.add(entry.getKey());
        }
}

for (String key : mylist){
        docf.remove(key);
}
```